# Program crashes when trying to insert new nodes to linked list. Why?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, structure

So I'm reading all the words in a file onto an array of linked lists. I have a separate linked list for each and every single letter of the alphabet.

Here's the structure:

```
struct WORD {
    char* word;
    int noOfUse;
    struct WORD* next;
};
```

And the array:

```
struct WORD* dictionary[26];
```

And the loop to read all the words:

```
do {
    fscanf(fp, "%s", buffer);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    dictionary[buffer[0]-'a'] = insertWord(buffer, dictionary[buffer[0]-'a']);
} while (!feof(fp));
```

And the function:

```
struct WORD* insertWord (char buffer[30], struct WORD* node){
if (node == NULL){
    node = (struct WORD*) malloc (sizeof(struct WORD));
    node->word = (char*) malloc (strlen(buffer)+1);
    strcpy(node->word, buffer);
    node->next = NULL;
}
else {
    node->next = insertWord(buffer, node->next);
}
return node;
}
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong her but the program crashes as soon as I run it. Am I trying to reach somewhere I don't want to reach?

Comment: Is `dictionary` initialized? Are the elements all `NULL`? And what if the input is not a lower-case letter?

Comment: By the way, if `node` is not `NULL`, then you have infinite recursion.

Comment: they are all lower-case letters in this case. does dictionary need to be initialized? i want all the elements of it to be null at the beginning anyway. i'd rather initialize them inside the function.

Comment: Your loop will also read a garbage word because you must test if fscanf returns 1; testing for feof() after using the result is a bug.

Comment: And why does every newbie reinvent casting the return value from malloc()? Don't do that.

Comment: our professors told us to always cast the return value of malloc. is it unneccessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `struct WORD* dictionary[26];` this can be initialized with garbage, you should probably set 26 pointers to NULL, also

```
else {
  node->next = insertWord(buffer, node);
}
```

this this executes if node != NULL and then you pass it once again to the insertWord function, then once again node != NULL and you start this function once again ..., it's infinite recursion.

Also remember about upper case letters.

Comment: thanks! it worked. silly me, I was supposed to send node->next as a parameter.